# Creating an age calculator using python by calculating current year - birth year

Tags: python, pseudocode

I've looked all over stack overflow and so I really need help. I'm making a program that is supposed to calculate the age of a person by asking for their birth year, validating their birth year is correct, as in a whole number, and not words or any other invalid types of answers. And then subtracting the birth year from our current year. I'm having trouble with the inputting our current year and subtracting the user input birth year from it.

```
    # Function Boolean is_valid_integer(String input_string)
    #   Declare Boolean is_valid
    #
    #   is_valid = is input_string a valid integer?
    #   Return is_valid
    # End Function

    def is_valid_integer(input_string):
        try:
            val = int(input_string)
            is_valid = True
        except ValueError:
            is_valid = False
        return is_valid

    # Function Integer get_year_born()
    #   Declare Boolean is_valid
    #
    #   Display "What year were you born in? "
    #   Input input_string
    #   Set is_valid = is_valid_integer(input_string)
    #   While Not is_valid
    #       Display "Please only enter whole years."
    #       Input input_string
    #       is_valid = is_valid_integer(input_string)
    #   End While
    #   input_integer = int(input_string)
    #   Return input_integer
    # End Function

    def get_year_born():
        input_string = input("What year were you born in? ")
        is_valid = is_valid_integer(input_string)
        while not is_valid:
            input_string = input("Please only enter whole years. ")
            is_valid = is_valid_integer(input_string)
        input_integer = int(input_string)
        return input_integer

    # Function Integer calculate_difference()
    #   difference = 2017 - input_integer
    # End Function

    import datetime
    def calculate_difference(difference):
        difference = 2017 - input_integer
        return difference



    # Module calculate_age_year()
    #   Set born = get_year_born()
    #   Call calculate_difference()
    # End Module

    def calculate_difference():
        print("Your age is: ", difference)

    calculate_age_year()
```

After trying to import datatime into my coding, it didn't work well. I was also not looking to calculate specific days and/or time, and so I removed those part of the suggested coding, maybe that had something to do with it?

My purpose for this program is really to just calculate years, so if I'm born in 2000, I'd like the program to calculate from 2017, meaning I'd be 17 years old as of right now.

My first function is the loop to void out false inputs, the second function is to get the year the user was born in, the third function is supposed to be calculating the difference between the current date and the user's birth date, and the fourth function outputting the user's actual age.

Comment: In your get_number_of_age() method your not doing any subtraction.  Where is age = current_year - input_integer ... all you're doing is returning user input.

Comment: sounds like homework?  break it into steps 1) get age.  2) validate age  3) do something with it.  focus on the individual steps first.

Comment: Show your actual attempt.  "when I actually enter something along the lines of..." doesn't show us what you are actually doing so  we can't tell you how to fix it.  As it stands, `today` isn't defined, so your code crashes when calling "calculate_age_year()".

Answer (score 0):

To work with the dates in Python, you can use the module `datetime`.

To validate the error, a pythonic way of doing would be to use `try...catch` to convert the user input to a date time. Catch the possible errors and do your error management from there.

Here is a simple example:

```
import datetime


def print_age():
    year = raw_input('Enter your age (YYYY/MM/DD): ')

    try:
        year = [int(i) for i in year.split('/')]
        birth_data = datetime.date(year[0], year[1], year[2])

        today = datetime.date.today()
        time_diff = today - birth_data

        print('Your age is: {} year and {} days'. format(
            time_diff.days // 365, time_diff.days % 365))
    except ValueError, KeyError:
        # Do your error management here
        print('Please use the format YYYY/MM/DD')


print_age()
```

With this, it should be relatively simple to return `True` or `False` and put the function in a loop.

**Edit**

Here is a piece of code that asks the user for his year of birth and prints the difference:

```
import datetime

year = None
while year is None:
    try:
        user_input = raw_input('Enter your date of birth (YYYY): ')
        year = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print('Your did not enter a valid year!')

print('You were born {} years ago'.format(datetime.datetime.now().year - year))
```

It does not check for the validity of the year though, if you enter 61241, it will not return an error.

You can add a layer of verification that check the range of the year if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I don't want the program to calculate specific days or time, just the year. Could you help me out a little more? I've tried importing datetime before and after you mentioned it, but I feel like I may be using it wrong and so it's not working? I've added it in the way I thought it'd work (the last way I tried is the current I posted), and it does not work. Any advice will be very helpful!

Comment: You can check the edit, it should be closer to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Currently still working on it, thank you for all of your help so far. My assignment was to choose any kind of program to code really, and I chose to code a calculator that calculates your age by taking the year you're born in (input), and subtracting from the current year we're in (2017). Unfortunately, everything has to have it's own block, for input, output, etc... This is my code for that block right now if you could take a look and let me know?

Comment: def calculate_difference(difference):                                                                                     
  

  difference = datetime.datetime.now().year - input_integer
  


  return difference